# Empty object response on fetching data from a local JSON server in React

Tags: reactjs, json, state, undefined, json-server

I`m trying to display the data from a local JSON server but I get into errors.

I know that fetch returns a promise which is asynchronous and it takes couple of milliseconds to succesfully fetch the data but my question is, how can I avoid or ignore the first empty object response and only execute the map on the data when it`s fetched because I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "map)"

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/data")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Data failed to fetch");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoaded(true);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card data={data} loaded={loaded} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Card = ({ data, loaded }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.activeUsers.user432.map((user) => (
        <h1 key={user.id}>{user.id}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Refer: https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering

Comment: you cant map through any other shape of data instead of array. just check the shape of your data or fill it with an empty array in initializing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
{ data.activeUsers?.user432.map((user) => (
        <h1 key={user.id}>{user.id}</h1>
      ))}
```